# svg fill animation does not work in firefox

Tags: css, svg, fill, svg-animate

Does anybody know why this code doesnt work in FF ? In chrome everything is ok but not in FF. The dots dont fill with the white color, just stay unfilled.

```
 <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 129.57 26.18">
      <defs>
        <style>.cls-1{fill:none;stroke:#fff;stroke-miterlimit:10;stroke-width:2px;}</style>
      </defs>
      <title>kropeczki</title>
      <g id="Warstwa_2" data-name="Warstwa 2">
        <g id="Layer_1" data-name="Layer 1">

          <circle class="cls-1" cx="13.09" cy="13.09" r="12.09">
        <animate
        attributeName="fill" from="none" to="#fff" begin="0.7" dur=".1s" fill="freeze" repeatCount="1"/>  
          </circle>
          <circle class="cls-1" cx="64.79" cy="13.09" r="12.09">
            <animate
        attributeName="fill" from="none" to="#fff" begin="1" dur=".1s" fill="freeze" repeatCount="1"/> 
          </circle>
          <circle class="cls-1" cx="116.49" cy="13.09" r="12.09">
            <animate
        attributeName="fill" from="none" to="#fff" begin="1.3" dur=".1s" fill="freeze" repeatCount="1"/>
          </circle>
        </g>
      </g>

    </svg>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the SVG and SMIL specifications durations are not allowed to start with a full stop. Adding a leading 0 as the specification demands so that .7 becomes 0.7 fixes things in Firefox.

I've also added a background rect as white on white does not show up too well in a snippet.

```html
     <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 129.57 26.18">
          <defs>
            <style>.cls-1{fill:none;stroke:#fff;stroke-miterlimit:10;stroke-width:2px;}</style>
          </defs>
          <title>kropeczki</title>
          <g id="Warstwa_2" data-name="Warstwa 2">
            <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="black"/>
            <g id="Layer_1" data-name="Layer 1">
              
              <circle class="cls-1" cx="13.09" cy="13.09" r="12.09">
            <animate
            attributeName="fill" from="none" to="#fff" begin="0.7" dur="0.1s" fill="freeze" repeatCount="1"/>  
              </circle>
              <circle class="cls-1" cx="64.79" cy="13.09" r="12.09">
                <animate
            attributeName="fill" from="none" to="#fff" begin="1" dur="0.1s" fill="freeze" repeatCount="1"/> 
              </circle>
              <circle class="cls-1" cx="116.49" cy="13.09" r="12.09">
                <animate
            attributeName="fill" from="none" to="#fff" begin="1.3" dur="0.1s" fill="freeze" repeatCount="1"/>
              </circle>
            </g>
          </g>
          
        </svg>
```

Comment: @Robert Longson 

Thank you :)

Comment: @LGSon sure it will, you just need to add the [fakesmile](https://leunen.me/fakesmile/) polyfill.

Comment: Yes, though not very fond of polyfills...I was more thinking about clean SVG/CSS :)

Comment: Btw, do you know why my solution doesn't work in Safari?

Answer (score 3):

Considering that SMIL doesn't work cross browser, may I suggest you use CSS animation instead

*Animate the color `none` won't work, use `transparent`*

```css
body {
  background: gray;
}
.cls-1 {
  fill: transparent;
  stroke: #fff;
  stroke-miterlimit: 10;
  stroke-width: 2px;
  -webkit-animation-name: setcolor;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 2s;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  animation-name: setcolor;
  animation-duration: 2s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
.cls-1:nth-child(2) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: .5s;
  animation-delay: .5s;
}
.cls-1:nth-child(3) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 1s;
  animation-delay: 1s;
}

@keyframes setcolor {
  100% {
    fill: white;
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes setcolor {
  100% {
    fill: white;
  }
}
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 129.57 26.18">
      <title>kropeczki</title>
      <g id="Warstwa_2" data-name="Warstwa 2">
        <g id="Layer_1" data-name="Layer 1">
          <circle class="cls-1" cx="13.09" cy="13.09" r="12.09">
          </circle>
          <circle class="cls-1" cx="64.79" cy="13.09" r="12.09">
          </circle>
          <circle class="cls-1" cx="116.49" cy="13.09" r="12.09">
          </circle>
        </g>
      </g>
</svg>
```

---

*Note, since Chrome favor CSS/Web animations over SMIL, the future of SMIL might be somewhat unpredictable, so I would recommend to wait using it until its future is more secured.*

Comment: Thank you very much,  it works ;) Now the problem is with Safari ;) ;)

Comment: @MarcinMroczko You're welcome. Don't have Safari so can't see. What goes wrong in that one?

Comment: @ LGSon

The same problem like before in FF ;) My first code worked in Chrome and in Safari. Your solution works i Chrome and FF :D 

P.S. I added prefixex required for Safari but did not help ;)

Comment: @MarcinMroczko Made an update...does it work in Safari now?

Comment: @MarcinMroczko I also made a net search and found many different ways to overcome this issue in Safari, though based on what you intend to do more with this, I can't say which is preferable, so check this yourself and use this search string as a start: `css animate fill svg safari won't work`